# What does rename() do when trying to move a file between directories on a samba mount?

Tags: linux, samba, rename

1. The share is mounted with `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=[username] //[ip_address]/[share] /mnt/[share]/`
2. I am accessing `rename()` via Node: `fs.renameSync('/mnt/[share]/file', '/mnt/[share]/folder/file')`
3. Both client and server are Ubuntu 20.04, Samba 4.12.5-Ubuntu.

Does `rename()` get passed to the server via SMB? Or does the client copy the file and write it back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Files in network shares are renamed on their disk, or renaming would have
been extremely slow.

The client might be using a different file-system from the server,
for example a Windows client and Linux server, so transferring the
file back and forth will lose information that is unique to the server.